# Why is linking successful when we placed definition of class in the header?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I've written the following code:

```
//--a.cpp--//
#include "base.h"


class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        A::bar();
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B *b= new B();
    b->foo();
    return 0;
}

//--b.cpp--//
#include "base.h"

void A::bar()
{
        printf("class A");
}


//--base.h--//

class A
{
public:
    void bar();
};
```

And it works. But I don't understand why it works correctly, but it doesn't work when we're put the `class A` definition into the `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` instead of `base.h`. I think that after *preprocessing phase* and before the compiling to object module the `base.h` just replaced to the content of `base.h`. And we have still redefinition of `class A` before the compilation phase.

Comment: What is the error you get when you define it in A.cpp?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I have undefined reference linker error

Comment: What do the undefined reference linker errors say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both a.cpp and b.cpp need access to the *declaration* of class A (which is what you have in base.h). I copied and pasted the contents of base.h (the declaration) at the top of a.cpp and b.cpp, and it compiled fine in Visual Studio 2012.

You do not want to put the *definition* of class A in both files. Classes can be *declared* in multiple places, but must be *defined* in only one.